# Calculating Pi using for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, pi

I have just made a program which calculates pi. However, even with 10 million iterations my result is kinda off. I get 3.141592**7535897831**, whereas already early on is it wrong. It is supposed to be 3.141592**653589793238**...

So my question is: What is the required amount of iterations to get at least an accurate answer all the way up to 10^-16

Here is my code if anyone is interested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
long double pi = 4.0;
long double tempPi;
for (int i = 1, j = 3; i <= 10000000; i++, j+=2)
{
    tempPi = static_cast<double>(4)/j;
    if (i%2 != 0)
    {
            pi -= tempPi;
    }
    else if (i%2 == 0)
    {
         pi += tempPi;
    }
}        
cout << "Pi has the value of: " << setprecision(16) << fixed << pi << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

*Any performance related tips would also be appreciated.*

Comment: How accurate is the algorithm? By that I mean in the strictest mathematical sense.

Comment: It is one of many methods to calculate pi. The algorithm is sound, although I suspect it is not the most efficient mean of calculating pi. The equation it derives from is pi = 4 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9... into infinity. I suppose that is why my method did not work since its original intentions were to calculate forever... :)

Comment: Nitpick: When talking large numbers, prefer C scientific notation: `1.0E-15` than `10^-16`. The `^` symbol can have various meaning such as exclusive-OR or exponentiation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the Leibniz series, which is very, very slow to converge. In an alternating series such as the one you are using, the first omitted term provides a good estimate of the error in the estimate. Your first omitted term is 4/2000005, so you should expect less than six significant digits of precision here.

Note well: Rounding errors, use of double precision numbers has nothing to do with the lack of precision here. The sole factor is that you are using a crappy algorithm.

Comment: Hehe... Agreed. This algorithm was provided by a book I am reading, and it asked me to make a code which iterated 1000 times. I thought that was kinda inaccurate so I tried 10 million times. That too was inaccurate, so now I am trying 10 billion times. This however seems like to much for my pc since it has been calculating for some time now... I should probably switch algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

There are [lots of methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_for_calculating_%CF%80#Efficient_methods) for calculating pi. Some converge faster than others.

Also see ["Modern Formulae"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Development_of_efficient_formulae)

```
the sequence 1 / a converges quartically to pi, giving about 100 digits in three steps and over a trillion digits after 20 steps.
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `double` is not nearly as accurate as you hope. You can't even represent decimal 1.2 with 100% accuracy.

I didn't look at the code closely to see if there are other problems.

Comment: This is not the problem here.

Comment: It may not be the technical reason for his observation, but *any* algorithm will never live to see more than a few digits of precision using a `double` datatype. There is no fix that will improve his accuracy as long is we stick with `double`.

Comment: Sure there is. Use a different algorithm. The Leibniz series has logarithmic (i.e., sublinear) convergence. Contrast that to the very first term of the Chudnovsky series, (426880*sqrt(10005))/13591409, which gives almost 14 digits of accuracy. Want more precision? Just one more term adds another 14 digits (which is a lot more than a double can handle).

Comment: Yes, and for maximum precision just use a literal value.

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is wrong after 10 million iterations due to round-up errors, you won't get the correct answer with more loops, only adding more error.